# Is this website copying Stack Overflow content and translating it to Russian legal?

Tags: support

I was looking for a code problem and I found a potential answer on Stack Overflow, but it was not the answer. So I kept looking and I found a Russian website which had the same question. I'm not Russian nor do I know the Russian language, so I translated it to English, and what I found was that this question was exactly the same as the one on Stack Overflow and even the answers were exactly the same.

Is this legal?

Here is a link to both questions:

http://qaru.site/questions/16453048/ckeditor-5-spaces-a

[CKEditor 5 spaces Â](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52370562/ckeditor-5-spaces-%C3%82)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The user contributions on Stack Overflow (and the rest of the Stack Exchange network) are licensed under cc by-sa 3.0 with attribution required.

Below the blue button with the thumb (a 'like' button?) is a link to the Stack Overflow question. The link text is "источник" which translates to "source". They also link to the author of the original question and display the author's name.
The same links are present for the answer.

At https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/ a number of requirements are listed:

> 1. Visually indicate that the content is from Stack Overflow or the Stack Exchange network in some way. It doesn’t have to be obnoxious; a discreet text blurb is fine.
> 2. Hyperlink directly to the original question on the source site (e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345)
> 3. Show the author names for every question and answer
> 4. Hyperlink each author name directly back to their user profile page on the source site (e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/users/12345/username)

Requirements 2, 3 and 4 are fulfilled. Requirement 1 does not appear to be fulfilled, but they've certainly put more effort in attribution than a lot of other copy-cat sites out there.

Comment: So practicly, that site is by the rules of cc by-sa 3.0 ilegal by broking the rule 1.

Comment: is this comment be accounted for? or do you have a source for this statement?

Answer (score 5):

You faced [one of the sites with auto-translated content from Stack Overflow in English](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7104/6). There are dozens of them, the same sites are available in many languages (for example, [es](https://webtapisblog.com), [ru](https://programmerz.ru)). I mentioned those sites in a [MSE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/316522/274323) about international sites' mission.

As [@Stijn said](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/377580/564240), most of those follow our [license](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/) and we cannot/will not do anything special about the sites themselves. At the same time I personally think that Stack Overflow is about *good* programming knowledge, which still is not true for machine translations. Currently we are [discussing](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8267/6) with our international communities how to make something useful out of this. Please feel free to share your ideas with us!